# Terraform repeat blocks

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a rather - I think - trivial question but I can not see the answer.

The [pagerduty terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/PagerDuty/pagerduty/latest/docs) allows to define a list of [targets](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/PagerDuty/pagerduty/latest/docs/resources/escalation_policy#targets).

We live a "Full Ownership, Full Empowerment" culture, so each team has assigned their own `.tf` file where they can reign their garden.
This is a classical team file:

```
# create the teams terraform landscape

locals {
  #some team locals
}

resource "pagerduty_service" "teletubbies" {
  #...
}

resource "pagerduty_escalation_policy" "teletubbies" {
  #...
  rule {
    escalation_delay_in_minutes = 10

    target {
      type = "schedule_reference"
      id   = pagerduty_schedule.draco.id
    }
  }
# PLACE OF QUESTION
}

resource "pagerduty_schedule" "teletubbies" {
  #...
}

resource "pagerduty_service_integration" "teletubbies" {
  #...
}

resource "pagerduty_extension" "teletubbies"{
  #...
}
```

Now, I marked a `PLACE OF QUESTION` in my code.

Our teams are actually motivated to operate their service "alone". But you know how it works, some things just do not work out. I want to add to each teams policy 1 or two more rules that will trigger when the owning team does not react to the alert (a safety net).

As I also want clean code I do not want to copy pasta around 15 (15 teams) times the same code.

I fancy something like this:

```
resource "pagerduty_escalation_policy" "teletubbies" {
  #...
  #owning teams rules
  
  template(escalation_rules)
}
```

I have found nothing that kind of "just loads text". I have seen that with TF>0.11 or so, you had a template_data provider, but this has been deprecated. I have also seen the new templatefile() but this seems to only work with an assignment.

The challenge I faced here is that e.g. templatefile() wants an assignment, you can not just do

```
resource "pagerduty_escalation_policy" "teletubbies" {
  #...
  #owning teams rules
  
  templatefile(file, vars)
}
```

because it will complain until you do

```
resource "pagerduty_escalation_policy" "teletubbies" {
  #...
  #owning teams rules
  
  xxxx = templatefile(file, vars)
}
```

which again is not what the provider wants of course.

Anyone has an idea how I can plainly render some definitions (without assignment)?

I checked modules but somehow this is also not what I need. I just need a "take a longer string and paste it neatly to the place I want" function.

Thank you for any pointers

PS:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 0.14.4"
  required_providers {
    pagerduty = {
      source = "pagerduty/pagerduty"
      version = "~> 1.8.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What about using modules? Can you put common resources with common properties in a module, and then use module?

Comment: I glanced at modules but all examples I find define resources as modules. I just want a text block in a resource, not a complete resource. Do you have an example where the module is just a text block?

Comment: The module suggestion is to wrap all of the resources and the logic (such as providing default escalation policy rules) into a module which then has a much reduced API/interface to it such as the team/service name, list of users on call for the schedule and any integration config and then configures everything based on that.

Comment: Yeah, this I got, but this is what I do not want. I want to explicitly just "complement" the teams' resources.
Although the modules bring up another idea. Actually one could invert this control, always rendering the default and giving the teams the option to add. Hmmm.